# Extract 1st Three Octets of an IPV4

Tags: mysql

Let's say there is a table having only one field. Table is named `address` and has a field named `ip` which contains an IPV4 address as its  value

**Sample Data**

```
192.168.120.201
192.168.120.202
192.168.120.203
192.168.120.204
192.168.120.205
192.168.121.3
192.168.121.50
```

I need to run a query on this table which will return data `COUNT` on The First Three Octets

**Expected Output**

> network      count
>
> 192.168.120  5
>
> 192.168.121  3

I tried using `SUBSTR`  like

```
SELECT SUBSTR(ip,1,10) as network,COUNT(*) as c FROM address GROUP BY network HAVING(c>1)
```

But the problem is that this `SUBSTR` will only work as expected if all the first 3 Octets have 3 digits each, but this will break on any ip address which does not have 3 digits each in first three octets. For example this will not work for

> 192.168.0.0
>
> 192.2.3.50
>
> 192.23.4.60

**Question**

Is there any alternate to the above query which will work in all the cases above?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't do string operations. you'd be better off converting the IPs to ints and using some bitmask, e.g.

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(INET_ATON(ipfield) & 0xFFFFFF00)
```

Comment: Great answer, but you still need to trim the trailing octet.

Comment: that'd be a display thing. since the final octet's been zeroed-out, you can group on the result of the inet transform. e.g. they'd all be `x.x.x.0`

Comment: Thanks Marc for this Elegant answer. Just like you, I expected this one to perform faster than the two answers given below. However on same data this query is taking `0.28` seconds whereas the `substring_index` one is taking `0.15` seconds. Is there any catch I am missing?

Comment: probably the double-string round tripping, since you're making mysql do string->int->masked->string, rather than just string->string. Personally, if I'm storing ipv4 addresses, i'll store them as an int, not a varchar. 4bytes v.s. 15. Also makes it easier to this sort of masking/ranging directly in the db, rather than having to do string hacking.

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense completely. Since my focus is more on counts rather than displaying the octets, I think I can use this solution without `INET_NTOA`. This then performs faster than `substring_index`. `INT` representation will do as good as `VARCHAR`. Thanks again!

Comment: sure. if you're just grouping on the masked value, then grouping on the int value works just the same as on the stringified version.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `substring_index` to do this:

```
SELECT substring_index(network, '.', 3) AS Octet,
       COUNT(*)
  FROM address
  GROUP BY Octet
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40a25/8) example

Comment: Thanks Martin, Great answer. +1, All the three answers given are valid, will decide the accepted one based on performance after running some tests

Comment: I like this answer, because of it's simplicity. It can be extended easily to 2 octets!

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` for this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip, '.', 3) as network, COUNT(*) as c
FROM address
GROUP BY network
HAVING(c>1)
LIMIT 500
```

Comment: Thanks Mike for this answer. +1